# Does Maven package dependencies by default?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, packaging

I have a Maven project with certain set of dependencies. One of the dependencies is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As long as I work in Eclipse, all is good. But when I package and try to use the resulting jar file(from command line if that matters), I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary
```

while this class is definitely accessible in IDE.

My guess is that Maven is not packaging project's dependencies by default but in that case why don't I get more error messages complaining about more classes that were not found?

Comment: is it a jar project or war project?

Comment: @sidgate Hi, the packaging is set to `jar`

Comment: @D.B. Amended the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven will only create a jar for your project/component. This does not include the external jars (dependencies). If you want/need to include the contents of the dependencies in your jar, you should create a fat jar or uber jar. For an uber jar, you may use [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was my guess to but how do I explain the fact it doesn't complain about few dozens other dependencies that this project has?

Comment: Maybe because they are not loaded yet by the ClassLoader.

Comment: or those are already present in your classpath